SPL Add the time from next row in new column
I am working in Splunk where I need to know what the difference is between two timestamps in the same column. My idea was to add the next value in a column to find the difference.
For example
TimeDifference
The reason is that I want to group timeframes based on difference > 900s. The timestamp is already rounded down to 15 minutes in this example.
Output would be like
Group into timeframes and give duration
Hope anyone can help here, I managed before in R using the first solution but maybe that there is a more convenient way of doing this

Splunk processes each event separately so it doesn't have a concept of "next row" or even "previous row".  You can, however, get the difference between two values of adjacent events using the streamstats command.
| streamstats window=2 range(<<timestamp field>>) as <<new field>>


Problem is, that I first need to round them and put conditions to it before I check the differences between time.
Maybe that there is a solution that I can group them in a timeframe with the condition there should be a 15 minutes gap between the frames?

The OP says timestamps are already rounded down so I did not include that in my answer.  Add bin span=15m <<timestamp field>> and other conditional commands prior to streamstats.
